# Increase performance of large tables from Plone search results

Tags: performance, datatables, plone, zope

The traditional way of Zope to handle large search results is batched output: The first *batchsize* items are displayed, and to get the next chunk of data, you click on a "next" link to get the next chunk from the server.

Nowadays there are cool Javascript solutions which allow client-side sorting and filtering of tables, e.g. `Datatables`.  These work fine; but if the table is large, and Zope generates the complete HTML, it sometimes takes a long time before the page loads (seems like the search is reasonably fast, but the TAL engine is the performance bottleneck).

So, how is this tackled best?

- Generate the whole table from JSON? (needs Javascript for anything to work)
- Use the standard paging, and replace it by a client-side table solution if Javascript is available?

  - provide the data of pages 2+ by JSON
  - provide all data by JSON
  - let the table engine load contents for next page or filtering
- Is there some plug-in solution to apply such enhancements to standard views (like folder contents)?

I have a page which contains about 1600 items and takes 60s+ to load, which certainly needs to be improved ...

Any pointers and/or code snippets? Thank you!

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, which is not the best for stackoverflow. https://community.plone.org might be a better fit as it allows a conversation.

Comment: I don't consider this open-ended; it might have occurred to many Zope/Plone developers. Perhaps someone has an elegant solution? I signed up at the Plone community site, but I don't feel comparably home there (yet?).  Of course, if there is a better place in stackexchange ...

Comment: Try advanced search solution, Solr or ElasticSearch, in such cases. The specific addon examples are collective.solr and collective.elasticsearch. However, I do not use them yet, and your mileage may vary. Hopefully the documentation should become more visible soon. Ref: http://github.com/collective/collective.solr/issues/60

Comment: @marr: From looking at them, both seem to be replacements to the catalog, using an external Java-based search engine. Both might be extremely cool and and worth a try, but ... my actual problem is not search performance. The search for the 60s+ page is done within 0.2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to roll your own customizations. The new folder contents in plone 5 works only with json data; however, it does not return the whole folder resultset at a time--it still does paging server side. I've actually not encountered anyone the use-case of sorting thousands of results client-side. I usually do that server side and bring in the data with ajax.

You'll want to generate json data structures yourself from catalog results(brains). Something like this in a view perhaps:

```
import json
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
query = {
  'path': {
    'query': '/'.join(context.getPhysicalPath()),
    'depth': 1
  }
}
result = []
for brain in catalog(**query):
  result.append({
    'id': brain.id,
    'uid': brain.UID,
    'title': brain.Title,
    'url': brain.getURL()
  })
return json.dumps(result)
```

Along with JavaScript. There are plenty of libraries to present json data in tables.

Things you can investigate if you're interested:

- https://github.com/plone/plone.app.content/blob/master/plone/app/content/browser/vocabulary.py
- https://github.com/plone/mockup/tree/master/mockup/patterns/structure

Comment: Why would anyone want to filter and/or sort big tables client-side?  Because it's easy. You simpy render the whole table and throw it at a cool tablesorting tool. It's much harder to make such tool talk to the server for paging and filtering; and in _most_ cases it is fast enough (after loading the page, it is _extremely_ fast, because no network communication is needed).

Comment: So Plone 5 will use JSON (and thus require Javascript), but keep the old way of paging?! For a standard solution I would have expected something which continues to work without Javascript, but adds convenience functionality (like client-side sorting and filtering) when Javascript is enabled ...

Comment: Why? Most things do paging server side. I've never interacted with a rest API where it returned thousands of records by default. Requiring a client to download thousands of records when they may only care about the first 20 doesn't seem optimal to me. Just because you have some use-case doesn't mean that all other use-cases are faulty. As you can see, it's very easy to provide your own json structure to do whatever you want with your huge result set so I'm not sure why you're outraged by "standard solution I would have expected".

Comment: I don't think you understood my argument. It's not about client-side vs. server-side; it's about _requiring_ Javascript vs. adding convenience functionality when Javascript is enabled. I don't know exactly how Pone 5 will do it; thus I repeated what I understood; I might be wrong.